# Using same expected rows for multiple expected queries returns result just for the first one with sqlmock

Tags: go, testing, go-sqlmock

I am writing tests with `sqlmock` in `go`. I have a list of rows (e.g. `myRows`) and two different `SELECT` statements which I want to use `myRows` as `WillReturnRows` argument for both of them:

```
myRows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"my_column"}).AddRow(1)
mock.ExpectQuery(firstQuery).WillReturnRows(myRows)
mock.ExpectQuery(secondQuery).WillReturnRows(myRows)
```

When I use it in the first `WillReturnRows`, it returns `1` as result. But in the second usage, no rows is returned as result; I mean empty rows returns. I printed out the `myRows` before and after first call in order to check if it's been consumed or not; the object had no change:

```
Rows Before:  &{[my_column] [[1]] 0 map[] <nil>}
Rows After:  &{[my_column] [[1]] 0 map[] <nil>}
```

**Edit 1:**

I used following code and it works; it means both queries return `1`:

```
myRows1 := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"my_column"}).AddRow(1)
myRows2 := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"my_column"}).AddRow(1)
mock.ExpectQuery(firstQuery).WillReturnRows(myRows1)
mock.ExpectQuery(secondQuery).WillReturnRows(myRows2)
```

Comment: You're assuming that the problem is with re-using an `*sqlmock.Rows` instance... does that mean that you've tried creating two `*sqlmock.Rows` instances and you've used them separately for the separate queries and in that test everything was working as it is supposed to?

Comment: @mkopriva, yes. This is exactly what happened. I will edit my question.

Comment: A quick glance at the [source](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/blob/master/rows.go#L124) suggests that the instance can't be re-used, you will have to create as many instances of `sqlmock.Rows` as the select queries that you expect. Each time your code calls `Next` on the `sql.Rows` instance the position in `sqlmock.Rows` gets incremented and so... the second query has no more rows to scan.

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva, would you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick glance at the [source](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/blob/master/rows.go#L124) suggests that the instance can't be re-used, you will have to create as many instances of `sqlmock.Rows` as the select queries that you expect. Each time your code calls `Next` on the `sql.Rows` instance, whether directly or indirectly, the position in `sqlmock.Rows` gets incremented and so... the second query has no more rows to scan.